# Free function in C is triggering Breakpoint

Tags: c

I am trying to run a program of singly linked list.
In the delete at front function the execution stops at free function whenever I call the function.

```
void del_front()
{
    struct node *new;
    new = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("list is empty\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        new = head;
        head = new->next;
        free(new);
        printf("Node at beginning deleted\n");
    }
}
```

This is the code for deleting a node at the front of the linked list.
Am I missing something in the code?

Comment: you don't need a `malloc`.  `new` is already a `struct node*`; if you allocate that memory again you just create a memory leak (because you're not freeing the `malloc` memory).   And what is `head`?  Global variables only make things more difficult.  Don't use them.  Especially for the head of a linked list because that means you can only have one list in your program!  Otherwise looks fine.  Can you provide a complete reproduction of the issue you're seeing?

Comment: `sizeof(struct node *)` is size of pointer. If you want size of structure, use either `sizeof(struct node)` or `sizeof(*new)`. But what is the point to allocate memory in delete function?

Comment: Edited out the question regarding Books, since such questions are beyond what the Community Guidelines allow.

Comment: OT:  I was thinking disallowing book recommendations seemed pure draconian nonsense, but then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic#:~:text=Questions%20asking%20us%20to%20recommend,so%20far%20to%20solve%20it.):  "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: If you are asked to remove a book from a shelf, do you start by printing a new book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I missing something in the code?

Yes, you are allocating the size of a pointer, not the size of a structure. You should either use:

- `struct node *new = malloc(sizeof(struct node));`  or
- `struct node *new = malloc(sizeof(*new));`

It is likely you have similar allocation issues in the rest of the program, causing the code to have undefined behavior when you make changes to the node structures beyond the allocated size.

In the case of `del_front` there is no need for allocation, you should simply free the head node if it exists:

```
struct node *head;

// [...]

void del_front(void) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("list is empty\n");
    } else {
        struct node *tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(tmp);
        printf("Node at beginning deleted\n");
    }
}
```